# python latin-1 UnicodeDecodeError after switching to ubuntu 14 with couchdb cPickle binary data

Tags: python, ubuntu, character-encoding, couchdb, couchdbkit

For some strange reason my python code stopped working after I switched from ubuntu 12 to ubuntu 14. I can't unpickle my data any more. I stored the data in a couchdb database by converting to latin1 encoding.

I'm using latin1 because I read some time ago (I don't have the link any more) that it is the only encoding I can use to store and retrieve cPickled binary data from a couchdb database. It was meant to avoid encoding issues with json (couchdbkit uses json in background).

Latin1 was supposed to map 256 characters to 256 characters, which would be exactly byte by byte. Now, after system upgrade, python seems to complain as if there were only 128 valid values and throws UnicodeDecodeError (see below)

- old python version was 2.7.3
- old couchdb version 1.6.1
- old couchdbkit was 0.5.7
- new python version is 2.7.6
- new couchdb version 1.6.1 (unchanged)
- new couchdbkit is 0.6.5

Not sure you need all those details, but here are some declarations I use:

```
#deals with all the errors when saving an item
def saveitem(item):  
    item.set_db(self.db)
    item["_id"] = key  
    error = True
    while error:
        try:    
            item.save()
            error = False
        except ResourceConflict:
            try:
                item = DBEntry.get_or_create(key)
            except ResourceConflict:
                pass
        except (NoMoreData) as e:
            print "CouchDB.set.saveitem: NoMoreData error, retrying...", str(e)
        except (RequestError) as e:
            print "CouchDB.set.saveitem: RequestError error. retrying...", str(e)

#deals with most of what could go wrong when adding an attachment
def addattachment(item, content, name = "theattachment"):
    key = item["_id"]
    error = True
    while error:
        try:
            item.put_attachment(content = content, name = name) #, content_type = "application/octet-stream"
            error = False
        except ResourceConflict:
            try:
                item = DBEntry.get_or_create(key)
            except ResourceConflict:
                print "addattachment ResourceConflict, retrying..."
            except NoMoreData:
                print "addattachment NoMoreData, retrying..."

        except (NoMoreData) as e:
            print key, ": no more data exception, wating 1 sec and retrying... -> ", str(e)
            time.sleep(1)
            item = DBEntry.get_or_create(key)
        except (IOError) as e:
            print "addattachment IOError:", str(e), "repeating..." 
            item = DBEntry.get_or_create(key)
        except (KeyError) as e:
            print "addattachment error:", str(e), "repeating..." 
            try:
                item = DBEntry.get_or_create(key)
            except ResourceConflict:
                pass
            except (NoMoreData) as e:
                pass
```

Then I save as follows:

```
        pickled = cPickle.dumps(obj = value, protocol = 2)
        pickled = pickled.decode('latin1')
        item = DBEntry(content={"seeattachment": True, "ispickled" : True},
            creationtm=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),lastaccesstm=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
        item = saveitem(item)
        addattachment(item, pickled)
```

And here is how I unpack. Data was written under ubuntu 12. Fails to unpack under ubuntu 14:

```
def unpackValue(self, value, therawkey):
    if value is None: return None
    originalval = value
    value = value["content"]
    result = None
    if value.has_key("realcontent"):
        result = value["realcontent"]
    elif value.has_key("seeattachment"):
        if originalval.has_key("_attachments"):
            if originalval["_attachments"].has_key("theattachment"):
                if originalval["_attachments"]["theattachment"].has_key("data"):
                    result = originalval["_attachments"]["theattachment"]["data"]
                    result = base64.b64decode(result)
                else:
                    print "unpackvalue: no data in attachment. Here is how it looks like:"
                    print originalval["_attachments"]["theattachment"].iteritems()
        else:
            error = True
            while error:
                try:
                    result = self.db.fetch_attachment(therawkey, "theattachment")
                    error = False
                except ResourceConflict:
                    print "could not get attachment for", therawkey, "retrying..."
                    time.sleep(1)
                except ResourceNotFound:
                    self.delete(key = therawkey, rawkey = True)
                    return None

        if value["ispickled"]:
            result = cPickle.loads(result.encode('latin1'))
    else:
        result = value

    if isinstance(result, unicode): result = result.encode("utf8")
    return result
```

The line `result = cPickle.loads(result.encode('latin1'))` succeeds under ubuntu 12 but it fails under ubuntu 14. Following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128)

I did NOT get that error under ubuntu 12!

How can I read my data under ubuntu 14 while keeping the newer couchdbkit and python versions? Is that even a versioning problem? Why is that error happening?

Comment: `result.encode('latin1')` could raise that error if `result` is already a `str`. Perhaps check to see if `type(result)` is a `str` and if so, try to track down why it is a `str` now when before (under ubuntu 12) it was a `unicode`.

Comment: It is a `str` indeed! Now I used `isinstance` to differentiate and unpickle a `str` directly. However it still failed with: _UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '�'._ I doublechecked and the same data entry unpickles just fine under ubuntu 12.

Comment: `cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps(10, protocol=2).decode('latin1').encode('utf-8'))` raises a similar error. Therefore, `result` might be a utf-8 encoded `str`. Try `cPickle.loads(result.decode('utf8').encode('latin1'))`.

Comment: If that works, then the *real* solution is to track down where `result` is getting `utf-8` encoded and stopping that from happening.

Comment: ... or change `utf-8` to `latin-1` at that point. In general it is good to work in terms of unicode and encode to bytes only at the interface between your program and the outside (e.g. when writing to a file, printing to the screen, sending data across a network, etc.)

Comment: `cPickle.loads(result.decode('utf8').encode('latin1'))` worked! Thanks a lot. If you write an official answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is some change -- possibly in couchdbkit's API -- which
makes `result` a UTF-8 encoded `str` whereas before it was `unicode`.

Since you want to encode the `unicode` in `latin1`, the work-around is to use

```
cPickle.loads(result.decode('utf8').encode('latin1'))
```

Note that it would be better to find where `result` is getting UTF-8 encoded and
either preventing that from happening (so you still have `unicode` as you did
under Ubuntu 12) or changing the encoding to `latin1` so that `result` will
already be in the form you desire.